# How can I make my TestCafe framework handle A/B experiments on web apps?

Tags: testing, automation, testcafe, ab-testing

I have built an automation framework for testing our web app that runs as after each new deploy to our staging environment, as a regression pack. Now the issue is the tests fail whenever there's a new experiment that touches that specific part of the tests, e.g., the home page validation tests fail if there is a new home page experiment. I'd like to know how I can make my tests robust enough to resolve the issue maybe by ignoring experiments altogether or always ensuring the page loads in the current non-experiment group?

I thought maybe a possible solution would be for the web team to write a new cookie than controls the experiments, and then just set that cookie in a hook prior to my tests? Would that work or is there maybe a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution with the cookie that controls your A/B experiments will work well with TestCafe. TestCafe allows you to work with cookies using the [ClientFunctions](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/) mechanism or [Client Scripts](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/inject-scripts-into-tested-pages.html).

Comment: Since [1.19.0 version](https://testcafe.io/403938/release-notes/framework/2022-05-26-testcafe-v1-19-0-released#cookie-management) TestCafe ships with a dedicated cross-browser cookie management API that allows one to manipulate browser cookies even if the `HttpOnly` flag is specified.

```js
await t.setCookies({ name: 'apiCookie1', value: 'value1' });
const cookies = await t.getCookies('apiCookie1');
```